# Question about the Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x)$  for which $\int_0^\infty |f_n(x)|dx$ (Riemann) exists with $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ (g(x) L-integrable) for all n and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ also continuous. Hence $f_n(x)$ is also Lebesgue intagrable and according to the Dominated convergence theorem we can assume $\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\int f_n=\int f $ (Lebesgue). My question is can we also assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx$ = $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ for the Riemann Integral?

Comment: Is $1$ your dominating function? That isn't an integrable function over $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Where the Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are both defined, they must be equal.

Comment: Isnt 1 Lebesgue integrable? In our lecture we included infinity for positive lebesgue  integrals.

Comment: How can one conclude that statement? I was wondering because  in our text book it only says , if the improper riemann integral of $|f|$ exists, then the lebesgue integral of $f$ exists.

Comment: Finiteness of the integral of the dominating function is part of the hypothesis of dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Yeah you are right , better change that in my sheet .